# Push to remote from zip git backup

Tags: git, bitbucket

So someone in my organization accidentally deleted a git code repo. Fortunately, a zip file containing all the branches (in the .git folder) has been recovered.
I have set up a new repo in BitBucket, by default it creates a README.md file in a 'main' branch.

How can I push a branch from my local repo to the new remote repo?

What I tried:

1. Added a new remote called "bitbucket"
2. git push bitbucket main. got this hint: Updates were rejected
   because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
3. git pull bitbucket main
4. git merge bitbucket/main --allow-unrelated-histories
5. resolve conflict and commit
6. git push bitbucket main. I get same error as number 2

Seems like I am stuck in a loop. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this.

Update:

Tried --force but got this error:

remote: Commits do not meet the Jira issues requirement.

remote: No Jira issues found in the following commits:

remote: f077889938c Added README.md

Comment: I would follow [official documentation on the topic](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/restore-a-deleted-repository-for-bitbucket-server-942841062.html)

Comment: Do a force push. You don't want to merge in whatever initial stuff Bitbucket happened to create. That's just noise in your history.

Comment: The proble with foce is that I get remote: Commits do not meet the Jira issues requirement. (see update on question)

Comment: `Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote`& `Added a new remote called "bitbucket"` makes me guess that the new repository was not created as an empty repository but instead has one or more initial commits with a readme file, .gitignore etc. This is the wrong approach for what you are attempting to do, but you can compensate by force pushing like others have pointed out (AFTER you have made really, really, really, really sure that you only overwrite what you intend to do).

Comment: The rejection due to content of commit messages is a completely different issue. That is only solvable by temporarily disabling some bitbucket specific setting which I have no idea what is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end my solution was to do a force push, but first some settings had to be changed in bitbucket to allow commits without Jira issues in them:
[image]